# Multiple Vlookup for identifying a customers name or business

Tags: excel, vlookup

I want to create a multiple vlookup to match records on an ID from two sheets. If the column reference does not exist I want it to look at a different column.

This is what I have already:

```
 =IF(VLOOKUP(A2,'Roots data'!F$2:Y$1139,18,0)>0,VLOOKUP(A2,'Roots data'!    
  F$2:Y$1139,17,0))
```

18 being the column which I want to check first and 17 being the column I want to check second. Can you please advise why this is not working appropriately?

Sample data:

Table 1:

```
ID First Name    Last Name  Age/Road
1  James          John
2  John           Miller
```

Table 2:

```
ID Age      Address
1  21       1 Road
2  22       2 Road
```

In this example, if I wanted to find the Age of ID 1 which is James I would do a vlookup to identify this, if the age was not present I instead would want to know the address for ID 1, to be populated under Age/Road in Table 1.

Comment: I think You want If(isna(vlookup())) not if(Vlookup()>0)

Comment: Unfortunately this hasn't resolved what I was expecting

Comment: @JeffUK please show a small sample of your worksheets using a picture for example so we can help you out better. And explain what it needs to find in column 17 to work and if it doesnt when it should search in column 18

Comment: Hi, I have added some sample data and more explanation on what is required.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

`=IF((VLOOKUP(A2,'Roots data'!F$2:Y$1139,18,FALSE)=0),VLOOKUP(A2,'Roots data'!F$2:Y$1139,17,FALSE), VLOOKUP(A2,'Roots data'!F$2:Y$1139,18,FALSE))`

Comment: Hi, this only returns the name if available and it does not look to the other reference to 17 :(

Comment: So if there is some data in Column 18, it will return that, if there isn't any data in that column, it will look at Column 17 instead...

Comment: ill review again and will get back to you shortly thanks!